# Print ticket from PWA in android (or print to pdf)

Tags: android, css, angular, progressive-web-apps, zebra-printers

I can print in Chrome for desktop, but when I install my PWA in android it's not showing content.

To make a PWA I install `@angular/pwa`.

This is my `app.component.html` config por printing in a router-oulet named:

```
<router-outlet  class="no-print-route">
  <app-spinner></app-spinner>
</router-outlet>

<router-outlet name="print"> </router-outlet>
```

This is the content of my `styles.css`:

```
@media print {
  @page {
    width: 80mm;
    height: 400mm;
  }
  html,
  body {
    width: 80mm;
    height: 100%;
    padding: none;
    margin: none;
  }

  app-full-component > * {
    display: none !important;
    padding: none;
    margin: none;
  }

  app-ticket-imprimir {
    display: block;
    padding: none;
    margin: none;
  }

  /* ... the rest of the rules ... */
}
```

And finally, I call mi `printService.ticket()` whit this logic inside:

```
 ticket(contrato: Contrato) {
    this._imprimiendo = true;
    this.contrato = contrato;

    this.router
      .navigate([
        "/",
        {
          outlets: {
            print: ["print", "ticket"],
          },
        },
      ])
      .then((algo) => {
        this.actualizar.next(contrato);
        setTimeout(() => {
          window.print();
        }, 100);
      });

    window.addEventListener("afterprint", () => {
      this._imprimiendo = false;
      this.router.navigate([
        "/",
        {
          outlets: {
            print: ["print"],
          },
        },
      ]);
    });
  }
```

This works well on desktop, but not in android. It`s show me only a blank page.

Comment: have you remotely debugged using the developer tools to find exceptions?

Comment: also, I have printed tickets to zebra printers from a PWA. Been almost 2 years now, so not a current thought on my end LOL. Just saying it is very possible. I wrote to the USB port directly.